# jsonResponse.getJSONArray not working

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm trying to fetch data from MySQL database which is on web server.
my goal is to retrieve array of location data which is already on MySQL database.
I'm getting this array of data from server,but I cant convert it from jsonResponse.getJSONArray to JSONArray object.

```
private void setUpMap() {
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener=new Response.Listener<String>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(s);
                boolean success=jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if(success){             //this is true, and also all the data is arrived
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");   //after this line it doesnt work,it doesn't enter in for loop
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String mac=jsonObject.getString("mac");
                    String android_id=jsonObject.getString("android_id");
                    Double latitude=jsonObject.getDouble("latitude");
                    Double longitude=jsonObject.getDouble("longitude");
                    if(!isMarkerOnArray(markerCollection,latitude,longitude))
                    markerCollection.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))));
                    }

                }
                else{
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Downloading position failed")
                            .setNegativeButton("retry",null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    DownloadPosition downloadPosition=new DownloadPosition(responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(MapsActivity.this);
    queue.add(downloadPosition);


}
```

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH4uM.png)

this is my php script

```
`<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
$sql="SELECT * FROM positions";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response["data"]=array();
$data=array();
$data["success"]=false;
$i=0;
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data["success"]=true;
    $data[$i] = array('id'=>$rs['id'],'mac'=>$rs['mac'], 'android_id'=>$rs['android_id'], 'latitude'=> $rs['latitude'],'longitude'=> $rs['longitude']);
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($con);
?>`
```

so my question is how can I get JSONArray object from jsonResponse.getJSONArray() ?

**edit:**
[this is json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm5UU.png)

Comment: What does your json look like?

Comment: What do you mean you can't convert it? What line is causing a problem, and what exactly is the problem? As @Apoorv asked, adding your JSON would be useful too

Comment: Can you post the JSON that is being printed? It doesn't look like your PHP Script is printing an array with the key `data`.

Comment: I just have added json.
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");
this line is causing a problem.which is that I can't get array in JsonArray object from jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data")

Answer (score 0):

You get the JsonObject in Response which contains the boolean and JsonObject.

So,Change in your PHP code,

```
$result=array();
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $result[$i] = array('id'=>$rs['id'],'mac'=>$rs['mac'], 'android_id'=>$rs['android_id'], 'latitude'=> $rs['latitude'],'longitude'=> $rs['longitude']);
     $i++;
}

$data['data']=$result;
echo json_encode($data);
```